# S4 won't connect with usb AND broken screen. Need files from phone

Tags: screen, data-recovery, usb-connection-mode, broken-screen

My S4 will not connect to my computer when plugged in using the correct samsung cord AND the screen is shattered. How can I load the files from the phone? Remove the hard drive from the phone maybe and put it in another without ruining the new replacement S4? And if there is no possible way a all to retrieve the files then what can I do to make sure no one else can retrieve them after I send the phone back to the insurance company? I have 4 days to get a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575) / [S3 screen broken, developer mode on, how to transfer data](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75248/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Theres nothing you can do to get the files unless your phone will connect with a usb. As for the screen if you can some how get the files off with a screen and no usb, then i advise you fix the screen for like $30-$60.

Answer (score 0):

No image at all on the screen? If just touch is broken, you can connect a keyboard/mouse with a OTG cable... no setup needed on phone.  Amazon has a few with prime shipping (2day)
[StarTech USB OTG Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B4GGW5Q)

Comment: screen is completely shattered and when I plug it in to my computer it does not show that the phone is plugged in. I am looking into taking the memory chip off the motherboard and putting it on my new phone somehow to get the file then switching them back after

Comment: @Brokenphoneguy - you can't take the memory chip off the circuit board, unless you have a micro soldering setup like the manufactures of the boards have. That being said, if you have a SD card in the phone you can pull that out and insert it in to another device.

Comment: Ok. Why might my phone not connect to the computer? How can I erase everything on the phone without connecting it to anything? Hit it with something? thanks